# Solve a symbolic quartic equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I try to solve a quartic function in Matlab using the Symbolic Math Toolbox.
Example:

```
syms x c1 c2 c3
solve(x^4+c1*x^3+c2*x^2+c3,x)
```

AFAIK, there should not be a problem in solving quartic equations analytically ([example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Converting_to_a_depressed_quartic)).
However, instead of the desired roots, Matlab returns

> ans=
>
> RootOf(X9^4 + X9^3*c1 + X9^2*c2 + c3, X9)

Any idea how to symbolically find the roots?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: Thanks to Luis Mendo for his answer. Unhappily, I am using Matlab R2010b, which does not support the `'MaxDegree'` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/symbolic/solve.html), you should use the `'MaxDegree'` option of `solve` (if your Matlab version supports it):

```
s = solve(x^4+c1*x^3+c2*x^2+c3==0, x, 'MaxDegree', 4);
pretty(s)
```

Comment: Unhappily, I am using Matlab R2010b, which does not support the `'MaxDegree'` parameter. But thank you very much for this answer, I'm sure it will help someone else! :-)

Comment: @Milan Same here. I haven't been able to test it